# @Query not finding component reference

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created a parent component that uses a child component internally. My aim is for the parent component to use my child components API, but I've been having trouble. Below is my code refined/condensed to the relevant areas.

```
class TripStop {}

@Component({
  selector: 'route-map'
})
@View({
  template: '...'
})
class RouteMap {

  setRoute(route: TripStop[]) {
    // Set the route!
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'route-plan'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <div>
      ...
      <route-map></route-map>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [RouteMap]
})
class RoutePlan {

  private stops: TripStop[];
  private maps:QueryList<RouteMap>;

  constructor(@Query(RouteMap) maps:QueryList<RouteMap>) {
      this.maps = maps;
    }

  public addStop() {
    this.stops.push(new TripStop());

    var routeMapComponent = this.maps.first; // This evaluates to undefined.
    routeMapComponent.setRoute(this.stops);
  }
}
```

So far, I've been unable to get a reference to the child route-map component within my plan-route component. From what I've read on the [Angular 2.0 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/QueryList-class.html), it seems as though I should be able to use the `@Query` decorator to inject a reference to any child components matching the query (as `ComponentRef` objects).

I've tried both using the component type within the query `@Query(RouteMap)` and adding an reference to my map element `<route-map #myMap></route-map>` then querying using that `@Query('myMap')`.

Confusingly, I managed to get the `@ViewQuery` decorator working and returning a reference to the underly map DOM element by adding a reference to my element & querying using that as described above. That doesn't really help me as I'd rather communicate with my component via it's API than modify it's underlying DOM - however, I think it indicates that the general wiring of my application is working as expected.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I'm using version `2.0.0-alpha.37`.

Answer (score 1):

As of version `2.0.0-alpha.37`, to get a reference to a child directive you can use the `@ViewQuery` decorator, passing the Type of the child component. To get a child DOM element, you can use the `@ViewQuery` decorator, passing a reference to the element.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Child'
})
@View({
  template: '<h1>I'm a child</h1>'
})
class Child {}

@Component({
  selector: 'Parent'
})
@View({
  template: '<child #myComponent></child>',
  directives: [Child]
})
class Parent {

  private childDirectives:QueryList<Child>;
  private childViews:QueryList<Child>;

  constructor(
    @ViewQuery(Child) childDirectives:QueryList<Child>,
    @ViewQuery('myComponent') childViews:QueryList<ElementRef>
  ) {
    // A query list of Child components.
    this.childDirectives = childDirectives;
    // A query list of views with the id #myComponent.
    this.childViews = childViews;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what the role of `@Query` is, nor am I sure whether `@ViewQuery` accepts any other selectors than IDs. This behaviour doesn't seem to be documented that well, and it seems a little unintuitive - however, it looks like the API is still changing in this area ([#3922](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3922)).